# Matlab - select all rows starting with a particular number

Tags: matlab, indexing

Say I have a matrix A, and I want to construct a matrix B that contains all rows of B that start with a particular number. How?
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Select all rows of B into A, where the first colum of B has value n:

```
A = B(B(:,1) == n,:);
```

In contrast to that, the following selects all rows of B into A, starting from row *index* n:

```
A = B(n:end,:);
```

Comment: No, I meant rows that contain the particular number. For example, if A=[1 2; 3 4; 1 7] and we look for all rows starting with 1, I'd like to get [1 2; 1 7]

Comment: I merged the other answer into that one.